# UI button in editing toolbar for backticks?

Tags: discussion

This has probably come up before but I did a quick search and didn't see anything on it.

Since the use of highlighting for `code specific elements` in a question seems to be encouraged, has a UI button for backticks been considered? I imagine this would sit next to the `B` and `I` icons in the toolbar.

Answer (score 3):

That already exists.  See the `{}` button in the toolbar.

[image: Toolbar]

It will surround an inline selection with backticks.  For a multiline selection, it will indent it 4 spaces, but the effect is the same:

```
code
sample
formatting
```

This is available when asking a question, answering, and editing.

Answer (score 3):

The icon could not help to understand its purpose, but its tooltip says more.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Ah! Ok, I've only ever used that for block code, never individual words.